# Delphi, search in text file

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

So, I have edit1 and edit2 + button on the form
when I put some number to edit1, after on button_clik it will search 12345 in the specified text file, if found, read string after delimiter or all line and pu it to edit2.

the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  var   sl : TStringList;   ix : Integer;

begin   sl := TStringList.Create;   try
    sl.LoadFromFile('C:\Polozky.txt');
    ix := sl.IndexOf(Edit1.Text);
    //d := SL.ValueFromIndex[IX];
    if ix > -1 then ShowMessage('OK')  Else ShowMessage('NOTHING');   finally
    sl.Free;   end; end;
```

hELLO, 
yes my file is comma seperated

```
12345,CAR
12233,BUS
```

.....
i would like to find 12345 adn put CAR into edit2.

Comment: You should start by reading some Delphi tutorials, preferably old ones (since Delphi 7 is old). Have you tried to Google something?

Comment: yes but I did'nt find reponse for tgat

Comment: What do you know how to do? Do you know how to read text files? Do you know how to search for text in strings? Do you know how to debug? As it stands, nobody can answer this in a useful way.

Comment: yes i know how to open and read file, i know how to find a string putted int edit1, but after that i don't know how to set text after finded string and put it into edit2.

Comment: `Edit2.Text := SomeText;`

Comment: For this momemt I use this

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  sl : TStringList;
  ix : Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromFile('C:\Polozky.txt');
    ix := sl.IndexOf(Edit1.Text);
    if ix > -1 then ShowMessage('OK') else ShowMessage('NOTHING');
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;

Comment: but instead of ShowMessage('OK') , i want to put the line where is fouded string into edit2.

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments. Edit the question. Show your code. Tell us what it should do and how it fails.

Comment: IndexOf checks for an exact match of the entire string. I still don't know what you want your program to do.

Comment: If each line of your text file is of the form   AAA=BBB   you can find the value by simply using  SL.Values['AAA']        If your file uses a different delimiter, like comma, instead of equals, you can set that using  SL.NameValueSeparator := ','

Comment: I personally don't much care for TStringList here. I'd read the file, parse, and hold in a dedicated structure. A dictionary would work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tStringList.Values` will search for a string of the form  `Name=Value`.
If you want to use a different delimiter, such as comma, set `NameValueSeparator`.
The code below displays the message 'BUS'.

```
var
  SL : tStringList;
begin
  SL := tStringList . Create;

  SL . Add ( '12345,CAR' );
  SL . Add ( '12233,BUS' );

  SL . NameValueSeparator := ',';

  ShowMessage ( SL . Values [ '12233' ] );
end;
```